# Python: Check if array doesn't have the required amount of members

Tags: python, sockets

I have a client-server project, in which I have a method `customs` which calculates customs payment when buying a car. It has two formal parameters: YearofProduction and CostOfCar.

In client command line, I type

> CUSTOMS 2017 20000

And get a return of X sum of money. Let's call `CUSTOMS 2017 20000` theRequest (so it's a string).

Python code in server:

```
data = conn.recv(1024)
point = data.decode("ASCII")
points = point.split(' ')
MESSAGE = points[0]
```

And to call it:

```
if points[0]=="CUSTOMS":
    if points[1].isdigit(): #the second argument is float, so .isdigit() is not working
        CUSTOMS(points[1], points[2])
    else:
        MESSAGE = "Input error"
        conn.send(MESSAGE.encode("ASCII"))
else:
     MESSAGE = "Input Error"
     conn.send(MESSAGE.encode("ASCII"))
```

The problem is that when I don't make an input of second argument, the server doesn't respond anything. How can I say like if points[2] == null (which can't be the case because of dynamic vector, points[2] doesn't exist).

Or, how can I make it so it checks how many member does the vector have? If 2 (the message (points[0]) and first argument (points[1]), then display the error message?

Comment: Either I am misunderstanding, or you are looking for the obscure `len` builtin.

Comment: Oh my! I didn't know you could use len in arrays. Yes indeed when I wrote s = len(points), it returned the amount of members. So I shall do something like if (s==3): #bllablla else: error

Comment: ***obscure len builtin*** :)

Comment: @timegeb Post it as an full answer so I can mark this question as done, so people don't need to waste time reading all the text! Thanks.

Comment: @Arti alright ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `len` builtin function to get the length of any finite collection (lists, tuples, sets, ...).

(Or to be more precise, anything that *is-a* [`Sized`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Sized) object, i.e. has a `__len__` method.)